# How to put a tcolorbox in one frame beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, allowframebreaks

I want to put a tcolorbox in one frame of beamer class.
I create the vd enviroment such below code.

Compiling the following code meets error
"File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body."
Please explain why it is and how to correct the code.

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[17pt, hyperref={unicode},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[most,many]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{vd}{\begin{frame}\begin{tcolorbox}}
{\end{tcolorbox}\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Contents of enviroment.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{vd}
    Contents of enviroment.
\end{vd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this has to do with the very sensitive way in which beamer frame environments collect their contents. The issue is described on page 61 of the [Beamer User's Guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637605/how-to-put-a-tcolorbox-in-one-frame-beamer) (v3.66; end of section 8.1).

Basically, when defining other environments using frames, it doesn't work well to have another `\end{...}` command in the closing block.

The Beamer User's Guide suggests getting around this by defining further commands that begin and start the inner environment, like this:

```
\documentclass[17pt, hyperref={unicode},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[most,many]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{vd}{\begin{frame}\tcolorboxstart}
{\tcolorboxend\end{frame}}

\newcommand{\tcolorboxstart}{\begin{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\tcolorboxend}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Contents of environment.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\begin{vd}
    Contents of environment.
\end{vd}
\end{document}
```